# How to enable user interaction for ViewControllers views inside UIPageViewContrller in swift

Tags: swift, tvos

I am trying to to add UIPageViewController as a child to the MainViewController, the UIPageViewController has 2 ViewContrllers, the problem is I can't interact with any of the views
that belong to the view controllers of the ui page view controller, can't press buttons I tried to make userInteraction enabled for all the views inside the UIPageView Controller
also tried the NSLayoutConstraint but couldn't get it to work , this is the way i added the ui page view controller to the main controller as a child

```
let uiPC = MyUIPageViewController(vm: vm)
uiPC.view.frame = containerView.frame
containerView.addSubview(uiPC.view)
addChild(uiPC)
uiPC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

also tried the constraint solution to set the view of the page controller with the view of the container view but no luck, can't get the user interaction to be enabled.
the only way that work is either adding the views of the ViewControllers as a subview or add the 2 view controller of UIPageviewContoller as a child to the MainViewController
[adding the UIPageViewController as a child inside the MainViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S558s.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behaviour of UIPageViewController in tvOS:

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller):

> Important In tvOS, the UIPageViewController class provides only a way
> to swipe between full-screen content pages. Unlike in iOS, a user
> cannot interact with or move focus between items on each page.

At the end I managed to get my design by embedding 2 view controllers in my view controller. A not interactive UIPageViewController in the background for the different pages, and another view controller on top with the buttons and clear background.

I also tried to implement an interactive UIPageViewController by using a UICollectionView with fullscreen cells and isPagingEnabled set to true. But, as documented, that is again not that easy in tvOS because [isPaging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619432-ispagingenabled) is no available in tvOS.

Comment: Thanks @David, Yes I figured it out already after reading the documentation but i forgot the question i posted here :) , I did add 2 VC as child to my Main VC and the only thing missing now is the dots that shows in the uipageviewcontroller, thanks again appreciate your time.

Comment: @SilentDev it sounds like we have followed the same path :) I managed to add the points using a UIPageControl. I hope it works for you

Comment: Thanks @David, that sounds cool can you share a snippet if you don't mind. appreciate your help